# How To convert NSManagedObject to Decodable class in Core data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am getting some server response and it is like below format.

```
{
    "sample_id": "Sample 1",
    "token": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "date": "Oct 20 2019"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "date": "Oct 08, 2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

and for this I have created Entity and declared **attribute** as **Transformable** type.

```
 static func fetchInfo() -> [Info] {
        
        // Create Fetch Request
        let managedContext = someMethod.getContext()
        let fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")

        var result = [Info]()
        do {
            // Execute Fetch Request
            let records = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if let records = records as? [Info] {
                result = records
            }
        }catch {
            print("Unable to fetch managed objects for entity \(String(describing: entity)).")
        }
        return result
    }
```

But, In above method its not going inside **records** and data not assigning to model (decodable) class.

And my decodable class is

```
struct Info: Decodable {
    
    let sampleId: String?
    let token: Int?
    let data: [Data]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sampleId = "sample_id"
        case token = "surveys_taken"
        case data = "data"
        
    }
    
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    
    let id: String?
    let date: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = “id”
        case date = “date”
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't name custom types the same as built-in types to start with so rename Data to something else. And you can't just cast a subclass of NSManagedObject to your struct Info, you need some code to map between the two. Maybe you can add the code where you save the Info into your store

Comment: I just given sample for Entity name as per privacy

Answer (score -1):

try to test like this

```swift
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Info> = Info.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self == %@", self.objectID)
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if let info = result.first {
         return info
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to fetch Info: \(error)", module: coreDataLogModule)
}

return self
```

Comment: What is INOLogError? And Info is a struct and not a subclass of NSManagedObject

Comment: @developer there is no objectiid attribute, I have one attribute which is Transformable type

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative Yes there is if self in this case is a NSManagedObject but this answer seems to be taken out of context so it's hard to know.

Comment: So, How to convert nsmanagedObject to Model class, Any suggestions?

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative We don't know what to convert since we don't know what/how you store in your entity.

Comment: print("Failed to fetch Info: \(error)", module: coreDataLogModule)